# Getting around null char from scanf

Tags: c, scanf, strtok

I have got my `strtok` working, but now because I am using `scanf` which ends the string with `NULL` char my program is only grabbing one line from redirected standard in. eg.

```
scanf("%s" , input);
    token = strtok (input, ", \n");

    while(token != NULL){
            i += (strtol(token,0,0)); 
            token = strtok(NULL, ", \n"); 

    }
```

So I am trying to use functions to check if the program has reached just a `NULL` of a `EOF` (from what i understand `EOF`  = -1 `NULL` = 0) but I'm having trouble getting the pointers and functions to work in my code. P.S. I know it's crappy code, but it's late and I'm still working on it while I wait for suggestions to point out my obvious errors that I'm missing.

```
int scanner();
int check_EOF();
int next_line(char *token);
int main(){

char *token, input[256];
int i = 0;


scanf("%s" , input);
    token = strtok (input, ", \n");

    if (!scanner())
        check_EOF();

printf("%d\n", i);
return 0;
}


int check_EOF(){
while(token !=EOF);
    next_line();
 }

int next_line(){
while(token != NULL){
    return 1;
else return 0;   
}

int scanner(){
while(next_line()){
        i += (strtol(token,0,0));
        token = strtok(NULL, ",")

    return 0
}
```

Is there an easier way that I don't know about or am I heading in the right direction with lots of errors?

Thanks, Lachlan

Comment: You can't compare a pointer to `EOF`; it's an `int` value returned by functions such as `getc` that read a single character.

Comment: @larsmans; but how can I use something like getc to compare to when ive already get the string with `scanf` won't it just call the next char or are you meaning to use something like `getc(token--)` to move the pointer to the previous char?

Comment: Like @larsmans said, `EOF` is a value returned by some functions, while `NULL` is a "zero pointer", and the terminating character of a string is `'\0'` and not the same as `NULL`.

Comment: Also, `scanf("%s")`  only scans until the next whitespace, which might be a space, tab or newline. You might want [`fgets`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) to get a whole line.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg; I did look at using `fgets` but it stores the `\n` char and the format that is being entered into this program only contains csv format with `\n` at the end of lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `man scanf`:

```
 The  value  EOF is returned if the end of input is reached...
```

You just need to check the return value of `scanf`, not `strtok`. Something like:

```
while(scanf("%s", input) != EOF)
   //just do it
```

Comment: I did just do it and a problem the last line entered doesn't get used i'm assuming because it contains EOF either that or i need to read AGAIN what happens if the second occuance of `strtok` does't contain `NULL` as the first parm

Comment: I did not quite understood your comment correctly. You have to understand one thing, the EOF is not a character, it's an error code. It's not written in the file, it's returned by the functions which do io on the file. This is why you can't just read the file and check if the characters you read contain EOF.

Answer (score -1):

Check you format of scanf.

You are missing the address operator '&' .

Comment: he's passing a char array. Don't need to add &

Comment: but im scannng to an array so I shouldn't need the `&` should i?